# Getting Proxy Authorization Error when trying to hit an API hosted at local host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, proxy

I am behind corporate firewall, but the resources which I am trying to access are within my network. I am using POSTMAN to call my POST/GET APIs hosted at my localhost:8000. These API's consumes other services hosted in my corporate kubernets cluster. My localhost and the service hosted at kubernets cluster both are reachable but when I am running my application and hit the endpoint of my API (the one which is hosted locally), it returns Proxy Authorization Error - at the endpoint of service hosted in kubernets.

I am really confused. Any clue why I am getting this strange proxy issues. Adding the Env Variable for http_proxy and https_proxy doesn't help as it blocks my POSTMAN from reaching any endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want proxy to be used for this connection. You should add your cluster to the no_proxy environment variable. Your Corporate proxy has no idea what localhost is and will fail.

See this question for info on the no_proxy environment variable
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/set-a-network-range-in-the-no-proxy-environment-variable